# Log4Net Unity Test Console Standard Output

Tags: c#, unit-testing, log4net

I have a problem with Log4Net Appender.
I run a Unity Test and want the Logs in my Unity Testresult Output

My File Apprender is working, now i have 2 more: Console and Trace Appender.

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="c:\tmp\Roche.NewGen.SSST.WorkflowScheduler.Tests.log"/>
  <appendToFile value="false" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="9" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <header value="Date:170?Thread:70?Level:62?Logger:300?Message[EOL]&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <conversionPattern value="[%utcdate][%level][Logger:%logger][Thread:%thread][Source:%type.%M:%L] %message %exception[EOL]%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="[%utcdate][%level][Logger:%logger][Thread:%thread][Source:%type.%M:%L] %message %exception[EOL]%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="[%utcdate][%level][Logger:%logger][Thread:%thread][Source:%type.%M:%L] %message %exception[EOL]%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
  <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

**Console Appender:** It does just nothing i can see....

**Trace Appender:** It just writes in the console while Debugging.

But i need the logs in the final "Standard Console Output". But there nothing is visible...

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using mstest/nunit/xunit?